# Call JavaScript setTimeout callback before delay expires

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a function which starts a timeout, if the time allocated to the timeout is met the timeout's code runs.

However I also want to make it so that another function can prematurely make the timeout run.

I know JavaScript has a "[clearTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)" api as seen in the example below:

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello") }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

However I couldn't find any api to make a timeout run prematurely. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't understand the question, if you want to initialize the timeout, call `myFunction`?

Comment: there is no such "built in" thing in javascript, though it's fairly easy to create something that will work that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language itself has no concept to apply your case,  you can stop the timeout but you cant force to make the execution at any time you want by a build in function.

```
function timeout(fn, timer) {
  var timerId = setTimeout(fn,timer);
  return {
    clear: function() {
       clearTimeout(timerId);
    },
    forceExecute: function() {
      this.clear();
      fn();
    } 
  } 
}
```

Try this it may help

Comment: Did you mean `return { clear: function() { clearTimeout(timerId); } ...` as it is, you'll clear the timeout everytime.

Comment: Sorry you're right I was typing by phone )) just editted